# How do I create circular patches within two radii in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, patch

I am trying to create a polar plot with circular rings of constant values. I am able to create the patches, but do not know how to 'constrain' the colored values to the area between two radii. This is what I have so far - this is just a sample and does not contain any real values. I'm just trying to figure out how to code this right now.

Arbitrary values below. The colorbar values are set to be ranging from 0-40, and the two patch cdata values are set at 28 and 35.

```
    numPoints=100; 
    radius=100;      
    theta=linspace(0,2*pi,numPoints);
    rho=ones(1,numPoints)*radius; 
    [X,Y] = pol2cart(theta,rho); 

    radius=20;
    rho=ones(1,numPoints)*radius;
    [X,Y] = pol2cart(theta,rho);
    H=patch(X,Y,1); 
    set(gca,'CLim',[0 40])
    cdata = ones(1,100)*28;
    set(H,'FaceColor','interp',...
    'CData',cdata,...
    'CDataMapping','scaled',...
    'EdgeColor','interp',...
    'LineWidth',5)
     colormap(jet)
     hold on

     radius=10;
     rho=ones(1,numPoints)*radius;
     [X,Y] = pol2cart(theta,rho);
     H=patch(X,Y,1); 
     cdata = ones(1,100)*35;
     set(H,'FaceColor','interp',...
     'CData',cdata,...
     'CDataMapping','scaled',...
     'EdgeColor','interp',...
     'LineWidth',5)
```

What this is doing is just writing over the first patch with the second, smaller patch. Because of this, there is no interpolation between them.

Comment: what do you mean by interpolation? I am not sure what you want or expect... transparency maybe?

Comment: I would like each circular ring to be color filled based on a single value, and then these blended with each ring extending further from the radius thereafter. Does this make sense?